# Unable to sort custom field on Account form

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

So I created a new custom field for Account called **Total Potential Revenue** of type **Currency**. But when I click on the field name to sort the data, it shows an "*up and down arrow*" like sorting but the data is not sorted. I tried changing the data type to **Number** or **Floating point** number but still unable to sort the data. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.
[image: Account form]

Comment: Weird. Is that field a rollup or calculated field by chance? Do OOB currency fields sort correctly? How about string fields?  Any plugins on RetrieveMultiple? Does the same issue happen on other entities? For other users?  In other browsers?

Comment: That custom field gets data from a REST service. OOB currency fields sort correctly. OOB string fields sort correctly too. There's a plugin on RetrieveMultiple of Account entity to query data for each account from a REST service then insert the data to that custom field. I haven't tried with other entities.

Answer (score 1):

Your RetrieveMultiple plugin needs to handle the sorting.  CRM is passing the sort expression to the database which doesn't have any data to sort which is why you're getting what seems like a nonsensical order.

Your plugin should pull the order expressions out of the request (if the query was a QueryExpression, for example, the order expressions are found in the `queryExpression.Orders` collection) and then sort your results accordingly before returning the collection.

Comment: This will only work fine when all queried records fit on one page.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen Agreed. If he needs to support sorting multiple pages by a column that comes from another system, then the plugin would have to handle retrieving the entire result set from CRM first so that the sort would be accurate (it also have to manually generate new paging info). That design would need to be carefully considered as it has obvious performance ramifications and is not beginner level stuff, but still doable.